# Delphi/Android - Show soft keyboard automatically below the grid when editing grid cell

Tags: delphi

I’ve been unpleasantly surprised at how difficult it is to find info on showing  the Android virtual keyboard 'below' the "grid" control. Seen some demos on showing the keyboard bellow the edit's but not for grids. Well, at least with the grid the mentioned demos do not work for me. Also did some search here but could not find anything for Delphi.

So can someone tell me in plain English how am I to accomplish this on 
Delphi Tokyo ?
I am totally new to android so something simple please ....  :)